# Problema con Bloque de código en C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

tengo problemas con este bloque de código, no me funciona. Estoy intentando hacer la eliminación de una fila seleccionada desde un DataGridView. No consigo que pueda estar mal hecho, el programa se ejecuta, pero no me toma la instrucción para eliminar la fila que he seleccionado. Alguien que pueda ayudarme.

Gracias.

```
private void dgvProductos_CellMouseUp(object sender, 

DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)

            {
                this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                this.dgvProductos.CurrentCell = this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dgvProductos, e.Location);
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.dgvProductos.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                this.dgvProductos.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);
            }
        }
```

---

hasta ahora esto es lo que llevo hecho, pero donde dice **"AQUÍ"**, con un punto de Debug pasa en ***"0"***, es decir, como si no tomase la fila que selecciono para ser eliminada. Y no avanza mas el programa, me arroja el siguiente error: ***Additional information: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.*** ***¿Alguna idea del porque?***

```
private void btn_EliminarFila_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                  
            ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvProductos.SelectedRows)
            {
                dgvProductos.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);

             **AQUI** ->  int selectedIndex = dgvProductos.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                var codeselec = _bdVentas.Productos1.Where(co => co.codigo_barra == Convert.ToInt32(selectedIndex));

                _bdVentas.Productos1.Remove(codeselec);
            }

            _bdVentas.SaveChanges();

            dgvProductos.Refresh();

            }
```

Comment: y que error te da?

Comment: No hay error alguno. el programa se ejecuta bien, pero cuando quiero eliminar la fila que selecciono, no hace nada... Realmente no consigo que pueda estar fallando en el código.

Comment: Y lo seguiste? esos eventos se ejecutan? es una muy rara seleccion de eventos para seleccionar algo en un grilla (que de por si, lo hace solo), y para confirmar la eliminacion (un boton no es mejor?)

Comment: Al hacer clic en la fila que selecciono, se despliega un menú donde selecciono la opción de "Eliminar", pero no funciona. _que recomendaciones me das tu? La verdad no he conseguido algo que pueda sacarme del rollo._

Comment: Pon un punto de depuración en el evento `contextMenuStrip1_Click` y mira si llega ahi

Comment: Este error es el que me sale: _**No se puede eliminar filas mediante programación a menos que DataGridView esté enlazado a datos con IBindingList que admita la notificación de cambios y permita la eliminación.**_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Esta ha sido mi solución:**

```
private void dgvProductos_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            this.dgvProductos.CurrentCell = this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dgvProductos, e.Location);
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }


    private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea eliminar el producto?", "¡Advertencia!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string _codigo_barra = dgvProductos.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            _bdVentas.DeleteProduct(_codigo_barra);

        }
        _bdVentas.SaveChanges();
        CargarGrid();
    }

}
```

Estuve probando con dos maneras para hacer la eliminación del registro desde el DGV. (Los dos códigos que deje en la preguntas) La ultima respuesta dejada por mi fue la solución correcta a mi problema. De hecho es mas limpia que las demás.

Y en esa solución, estoy implementando un SP, cosa que no hacia en las propuestas anteriores.

Comment: David podrias explicar porque las otras soluciones no terminaron de funcionarte? mas alla de eso, si esta respuesta es la correcta recuerda aceptarla.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto una aplicacion windows form que alimenta la grilla y luego al hacer doble click, recarga la grilla con el origen de datos cambiado.

1. Recupero el origen de datos con getdata y lo guardo en el datasource de la 
   grilla.
2. Cuando borro, lo hago sobre el datatable para luego recargar la grilla. Ver el handler dgvProductos_CellDoubleClick.

> ```
>  using System;
>  using System.Collections.Generic;
>  using System.ComponentModel;
>  using System.Data;   
>  using System.Drawing;
>  using System.Linq;
>  using System.Text;
>  using System.Threading.Tasks;
>  using System.Windows.Forms;
>     namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
>     {
>    public partial class Form1 : Form
>     {
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         dgvProductos.DataSource = getData(); //Recupero el origen de datos y luego refresco con Show
>         dgvProductos.Show();
>     }
>     static DataTable getData() //Cargo un origen de datos con la informacion de los productos. Lo hago en un datatable
>     {
>         DataTable table = new DataTable();
>         table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
>         table.Columns.Add("Colour", typeof(string));
>         table.Rows.Add("camisa", "azul");
>         table.Rows.Add("pantalon", "blanco");
>         return table;
>
>     }
>
>     private void dgvProductos_CellDoubleClick(object sender, >DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) //Cada vez que hago doble click solicitoconfirmacion para eliminar registro
>     {         
>
>
>         if (MessageBox.Show("Confirma eliminar el registro >seleccionado","Confirmacion",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question)==DialogResult.Yes)
>         {
>
>             DataTable table = (DataTable)dgvProductos.DataSource;
>             if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
>             {
>                 table.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
>                 dgvProductos.DataSource = table;
>                 dgvProductos.Show(); // Como es un window form actualizo el datasource aca
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

lo que conviene hacer es modificar el origen de datos y despues cargarlo de nuevo al gridview. Se asigna el datasource de nuevo y luego ejecutar un databind para refrescar.

dgvProductos.DataSource = table 
dgvProductos.DataBind();

La secuencia de pasos sería:

1. Remuevo el registro de mi origen de datos
2. Recargo el datasource de la grilla y hago el databind

Espero sirva.

Saludos.